# Adjustbox does not reduce table and tikzpicture widths

Tags: floats, scaling, adjustbox

I'm redesigning lecture notes for a university class since the students wanted to read the notes on their tablets, e-book readers, etc. So I've written a Makefile with different targets for different page sizes. The only problem I have is with some PGF/TikZ figures and some tables that are too large to fit on a small paper size.

I'd like to use [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox) to reduce the size of tables and figures drawn in PGF/TikZ, if they are too large to fit on the defined paper size. However, it doesn't really work.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% set page size with geometry
\usepackage[nohead,%
    nofoot,%
    nomarginpar,%
    paperwidth=106.68mm,%
    paperheight=142.24mm,%
    tmargin=2.5mm,%
    rmargin=2.5mm,%
    bmargin=2.5mm,%
    lmargin=2.5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

%define lengths for maximum figure and table width and height
\newlength{\maxtabfigwidth}
\newlength{\maxtabfigheight}

\setlength{\maxtabfigwidth}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\maxtabfigheight}{\textheight}

% decrease height a bit letting captions fit to one page
\addtolength{\maxtabfigheight}{-2.5em}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section*{Example \#1}

The width of the table isn't reduced to \texttt{\textbackslash{}maxtabfigwidth}.

\begin{adjustbox}{center,%
    max width={\maxtabfigwidth},%
    max totalheight={\maxtabfigheight},%
    captionbelow={A wide table},%
    float={table}[h!]}
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{6cm}}
\hline
wide & table \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\section*{Example \#2}

The width of the tikzpicture isn't reduced to \texttt{\textbackslash{}maxtabfigwidth}.

\begin{adjustbox}{center,%
    max width={\maxtabfigwidth},%
    max totalheight={\maxtabfigheight},%
    captionbelow={A wide tikzpicture},%
    float={figure}[H]}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (0cm, 0cm) -- (0cm, -3cm) -- (12cm, -3cm) -- (12cm, 0cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\section*{Example \#3}

The height of the tikzpicture is reduced to\texttt{\textbackslash{}maxtabfigheight}, however it is not centered.

\begin{adjustbox}{center,%
    max width={\maxtabfigwidth},%
    max totalheight={\maxtabfigheight},%
    captionbelow={A tall tikzpicture},%
    float={figure}[H]}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (0cm, 0cm) -- (0cm, -15cm) -- (5cm, -15cm) -- (5cm, 0cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

So the question is what am I missing or doing wrong? Is there any other approach for scaling down tables and figures if they don't fit on a small paper size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that you need to compute the values of `\maxtabfigwidth` and `\maxtabfigheight` later, because `geometry` does its computations at begin document.

The second problem is that the order of options to `adjustbox` is significant. In particular `center` must go after `max width` and `max totalheight`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% set page size with geometry
\usepackage[nohead,%
    nofoot,%
    nomarginpar,%
    paperwidth=106.68mm,%
    paperheight=142.24mm,%
    tmargin=2.5mm,%
    rmargin=2.5mm,%
    bmargin=2.5mm,%
    lmargin=2.5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

%define lengths for maximum figure and table width and height
\newlength{\maxtabfigwidth}
\newlength{\maxtabfigheight}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \setlength{\maxtabfigwidth}{\textwidth}
  \setlength{\maxtabfigheight}{\textheight}
  % decrease height a bit letting captions fit to one page
  \addtolength{\maxtabfigheight}{-2.5em}
}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section*{Example \#1}

The width of the table isn't reduced to \texttt{\textbackslash{}maxtabfigwidth}.

\begin{adjustbox}{
  max width=\maxtabfigwidth,
  max totalheight=\maxtabfigheight,
  center,
  captionbelow={A wide table},
  float={table}[h!],
}
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{6cm}}
\hline
wide & table \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\section*{Example \#2}

The width of the tikzpicture isn't reduced to \texttt{\textbackslash{}maxtabfigwidth}.

\begin{adjustbox}{
  max width=\maxtabfigwidth,
  max totalheight=\maxtabfigheight,
  center,
  captionbelow={A wide tikzpicture},%
  float={figure}[H],
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (0cm, 0cm) -- (0cm, -3cm) -- (12cm, -3cm) -- (12cm, 0cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\section*{Example \#3}

The height of the tikzpicture is reduced to\texttt{\textbackslash{}maxtabfigheight}, however 
it is not centered.

\begin{adjustbox}{
  max width=\maxtabfigwidth,
  max totalheight=\maxtabfigheight,
  center,
  captionbelow={A tall tikzpicture},
  float={figure}[H],
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (0cm, 0cm) -- (0cm, -15cm) -- (5cm, -15cm) -- (5cm, 0cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]